# Loading a GLTF or GLB into React Native GL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, three.js, webgl, filereader

I have been attempting to load a simple model into my `React Native App`, I have craeted a model in Blender and exported as GLTF and GLB. In my react native app I'm using expo-gl and threejs to load and render the scene.
 This is my page code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl'
import { Renderer } from 'expo-three'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import OrbitControlsView from 'expo-three-orbit-controls'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { storage } from '../services/firebase'
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'

class SphereMesh extends THREE.Mesh {
    constructor() {
        super(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' })
        )
    }
}

export function ThreeComponent() {
    // Animmation clock
    const clock = new THREE.Clock()

    const [camera, setCamera] = React.useState<THREE.Camera | null>(null)

    async function loadModel() {
        getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'niltontest/mymodel.gltf'))
            .then(async (url) => {
                // let blob = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.blob())

                // GLTF loader
                const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

                // await gltfLoader.parse(
                //  'file:///Users/niltonsf/Desktop/react-native-3d/assets/mymodel.gltf',
                //  '',
                //  (gltf) => {
                //      console.log('here', gltf)
                //  },
                //  () => {
                //      console.log('fail')
                //  }
                // )

                gltfLoader.load(
                    // resource URL
                    url,
                    // called when the resource is loaded
                    function (gltf) {
                        console.log('sc')
                    },
                    // called while loading is progressing
                    function (xhr) {
                        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
                    },
                    // called when loading has errors
                    function (error) {
                        console.log('An error happened', error)
                    }
                )
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Handle any errors
            })
    }

    // Mesh
    const cube = new SphereMesh()

    const tick = () => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadModel()
    }, [])

    return (
        <OrbitControlsView style={{ flex: 1 }} camera={camera}>
            <GLView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                onContextCreate={async (gl) => {
                    //  GL Parameter disruption
                    const {
                        drawingBufferWidth: width,
                        drawingBufferHeight: height
                    } = gl

                    // Scene
                    const scene = new THREE.Scene()

                    // Geometry
                    scene.add(cube)

                    // Camera
                    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                        75,
                        width / height,
                        1,
                        1000
                    )
                    camera.position.z = 2
                    camera.position.x = 2
                    camera.position.y = 2
                    camera.lookAt(cube.position)
                    setCamera(camera)
                    scene.add(camera)

                    // Renderer
                    const renderer = new Renderer({ gl })
                    renderer.setSize(width, height)
                    renderer.setClearColor('#fff')

                    // Render function
                    const render = () => {
                        requestAnimationFrame(render)
                        renderer.render(scene, camera)
                        gl.endFrameEXP()
                    }
                    render()
                }}
            />
        </OrbitControlsView>
    )
}
```

I have attemtpted to un a model from Firebase Storage and a local one. But either of them say the same error message, which is:

```
 An error happened [Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented]
```

Comment: Hey, I've been getting the same issue today - after an expo upgrade as I wanted React 18 etc...

Comment: Maybe it could be because of some version mismatch where expo-gl or expo-three aren't expecting the Expo 46 SDK but I'm still not sure. I'll keep you posted if I find anything  

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/1972